# Get specific column from a recordset

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get 20,19,17,16,21,32,33 only

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 19
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 17
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 16
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 21
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 32
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 33
        )

)
```

I need 20,19,17,16,21,32,33 value only.

Pls help

Comment: use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: I was about to ask myself why soo many down votes, but OP showed no sign of attempt to solve this

Comment: I trying but didt not get values

Answer (score 1):

use `$product_id = array_column($array, 'product_id ');`

check [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: This won't work.

Comment: @Adaleni its not working bro

Comment: @Script47 any other solution.

Comment: @GokulRajR try `$product_id = array_column($array, 'product_id');`

Comment: @Script47 but u said this wont work

Comment: @GokulRajR please reread all the information above.

Comment: @Script47 I got it bro but i need to output this Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 19 [2] => 17 [3] => 16 [4] => 21 [5] => 32 [6] => 33 )

to this 20,19,17,16,21,32,33

Comment: Thanks bro I got output @Script47